# Django requests printed in IDE over WEB

Tags: django, python-requests, pycharm

I am posing this questions since I didn't found anything that would already solve my little problem. I want to know if I can see requests over the internet on my IDE Pycharm or any other. Normally when I hosted site via localhost I saw requests I did, and I was also able to see printed suff. Now when I implemented WSGI, maping external IP to free hostname I don't see live requests anymore (all is hosted locally on windows with xampp apache2).

Comment: Assuming you have a fairly standard apache setup, have a look in the log files. They are probably in /var/log/httpd/access.log

Comment: use wireshark or set up a web developers proxy on your local machine

Comment: That are great ideas, but how about HTTPS. I know I am still able to see requests on my localhost address in my IDE if I use 127.0.0.1 (with http connection) but when I try https it says: code 400, message Bad request syntax ("\x16\x03\x01\x00|\x01\x00\x00x\x03\x02ç+\xc0f¤÷D0ü}L\xa1\x92\x1a\xc8§×\x10ÂÝ\xf0\xf0\x90\x93\x0e\x1fpe\x05\x1d'\x01\x00\x00\x10\xc0\t\xc0\x13\x
c0"). Is there a way to support visible https requests locally since it is much more convenient to be able to see them in IDE directly?